# How to access id in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user class, which has_many resumes, each of which has many items. On my users/show page, I render multiple resumes, which is working. In my users_controller I have the following:

```
def show
 ...
 @resumes = @user.resumes.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @resume = @user.resumes.build if user_signed_in?
 @resume_items = @user.res.paginate(page: params[:page])
 @edu_items = @resume.edu.paginate(page: params[:page])
 ...
end
```

I defined the function res in my User model:

```
def res
  Resume.where("student_id = ?", id)
end
```

And that worked quite well. However, I'm trying to do the same thing with the function edu in my Resume model:

```
def edu
  Education.where("resume_id = ?", id)
end
```

but it's not working, @edu_items isn't being set to anything. Now I know it has to do with this method specifically, because if I change id to the id of a specific resume, that resume's items are rendered correctly, except across every resume. I know it's a simple fix, I've just been staring at it for way too long at this point and can't figure it out. Any advice would be amazing.

EDIT: @makaroni4: Instead of having @educations = @user.educations, I'd rather keep the items from each resume separate. Is it possible to define a method like the educations one that will make @educations = @resume.educations?

EDIT 2: I managed to get what I was trying to do to work, thanks for the advice. I solved it by doing away with the edu method altogether, and passing local variables to the partial:

```
  <%= render :partial => 'shared/edu', :as => :educations, :locals => {:resume_educations => resume_item.educations} %>
```

shared/edu

```
<% if resume_educations.any? %>
   <ol class="educations">
     <%= render partial: 'shared/edu_item', collection: resume_educations %>
   </ol>
   <%= will_paginate @educations %>
<% end %>
```

Probably not the cleanest solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: Any reasons why you're not using standard rails relationships? (`belongs_to`, `has_many`, ...)

Comment: I am. Specifically, I have: user has_many resumes, resume has_many items and belongs_to user, and item belongs_to resume.

Comment: If you created those relationships in your models, you don't need these methods. You can just do `@user.resumes.paginate` and `@resume.items.paginate`. You are trying to do the work that Rails already does for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your model structure should look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resumes

  def educations
    Education.joins(:resume => :user).where(:users => { :id => id })
  end
end

class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :educations
end

class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resume
end
```

So in your controller you can access them like:

```
@resumes = @user.resumes
@educations = @user.educations # all users educations, from all resumes

or

@educations = @resume.educations # educations for particular resume
```

And also I recommend you to read this article http://petdance.com/2012/04/the-worlds-two-worst-variable-names/ about variables naming, variables like **resume_items** and methods **res** and **edu** should say that you're doing smtg not in the right way.

Comment: Sure, educations = resume.educations will work with my example, check my edit for the answer

Answer (score 1):

It does not work, because the result of your `edu` method will always be empty.

In your code you are building a resume object:

```
@resume = @user.resumes.build if user_signed_in?
```

If you use `build` an object is created, but not saved to the database yet. This means that your `@resume.id` is `nil`. And thus the result of your `edu` method will be empty.

You could use the following to create the record in the database:

```
@resume = @user.resumes.create if user_signed_in?
```

But your `edu` method will still return an empty collection, because it's a new record and it won't be associated with any items yet.

Please expand on what you are trying to do exactly, because with this code `@resume.edu` will always be empty for the reason explained above.

Also: consider using the built-in Rails functionality instead of making your own methods.

Comment: I think I managed to figure out what I was trying to do.. See edit above